Filtering outlook email based on a specific subject using python, but cant find email
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application") 
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
your_address = 'tonytony@outlook.com' 
inbox = mapi.Folders[your_address].Folders['Inbox'].Folders['Apples']

subject_to_find = "Data List of apples" 
email_found = find_email(subject_to_find, inbox)

def find_email(subject, folder): 
    # Get all emails in the folder 
    emails = folder.Items

    # Use Restrict method to filter emails with a specific subject
    filtered_emails = emails.Restrict("[Subject] = '" + subject + "'")
    
    # Sort the filtered emails by ReceivedTime in descending order
    filtered_emails.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
    
    # Get the most recent email, if any
    email = filtered_emails.GetFirst()
    
    return email

I want to get the latest email from the email conversation; the following code is not able to pick up any emails within said folder. But without the restrictions, it can run through the entire email conversation. Not sure what am I doing wrong.

Try to change your restriction to use PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT property
filtered_emails = emails.Restrict("@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F"" = '" + subject + "'")

and specify the value without any prefixes (RE/FW/etc.)

If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!
